# Loudspeaker on HTC One does not work while using Skype

Tags: skype, htc-one

I have an HTC One and I have Skype installed on it. I tried calling another Skype user who has a Samsung Galaxy S3, and chatting to her on Skype works fine, but while on a call the HTC switches its loudspeaker off.  I have to put the phone to my ear to hear the other person, which makes video chat impossible.

I haven't tried un-installing and reinstalling Skype yet in case it causes more problems.  There are no settings within Skype while you're using it that allows you to switch loudspeaker on/off.  Only for video and microphone are these options available.

Does anyone know why is this happening?